# Is the transpose of $T$ also the dual map of $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces, transpose, dual-maps

Suppose I have $T: V \to W$. Then $T$ defines a map $T': W' \to V'$ that some sources (e.g. Axler) call the dual map of $T$. And $T$ defines a map $T^t: W' \to V'$ that some sources (e.g. Hoffman and Kunze) call the transpose of $T$. My question is: are these synonyms?

Comment: Dual map, transpose map, adjoint map(though this has other meanings as well) all refer to the same thing: the function from $W'\to V'$ such that $f\mapsto f\circ T$.

Comment: Amazing. That is exactly what I was hoping you would say. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just elaborating on my previous comment. The reason we call $T'$ the dual map because it maps between the dual spaces and the word 'dual' is used because $V,V'$ are kind of similar but then again not really, same with $W,W'$ and $T,T'$. The reason why we call $T'=T^t$ the transposed map is because if you take a basis $\beta$ of $V$, $\gamma$ of $W$ and the unique dual bases $\beta',\gamma'$ of $V',W'$ then the matrix representations are related by transpose: $[T^t]_{\gamma'}^{\beta'}=\left([T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}\right)^t$.

Comment: Thanks. That's sort of exactly why I was asking. I'm trying to understand the relationship between "dual map" "transpose" and "adjoint". And what I've found, in short is, "dual map" = "transpose", and "dual map" = "adjoint" if you have an inner product so that you can identify the dual space of V with V itself through Reisz representation of linear functionals as vectors. (Although, it seems that also, from a higher level perspective which I don't yet fully understand, these distinctions begin to break down or seem less relevant, hence why the terminology at the lower level can seem murky.)

Comment: Theorem 3.114 of my book Linear Algebra Done Right (third edition) states that the matrix of $T'$ with respect to the dual bases is the transpose of the matrix of $T$.

Comment: @SheldonAxler Unbelievable. Thank you so much! I have to tell you: your book has changed my life. I read it almost a decade ago; it was my first real math book; and from that experience, I decided I wanted to become a mathematician. Now I'm two weeks away from my linear algebra qualifying exam. Thank you so much for all you do and have done.